# Embedding Google Map in a Jekyll Post

Tags: google-maps, jekyll, github-pages

I would like to embed a custom google map with on my personal static blog, which was built using Jekyll and is hosted on GitHub Pages. Ideally, users would be able to zoom in/out on the map and toggle the various map layers on and off.

Here is the map: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ELysbd_HcyENvsuK5auBFbFpwZ0&usp=sharing

Here is my personal blog: http://willgeary.github.io/biking/2016/05/20/biking-from-vancouver-to-los-angeles.html

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is add the code-snippet provided by Google Maps to your post or page:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1ELysbd_HcyENvsuK5auBFbFpwZ0" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

You get this code by clicking the 3 dots button and selecting "Embed map"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Caio ! I was aware of this functionality but was over thinking the problem. All set now. Appreciate your response!